# Unable to build android version with forge on trigger platform 2.5.5

Tags: android, trigger.io

After updating to trigger platform version 2.5.5 (coming from 2.2.16). Forge is no longer able to build an android version of the app.

This is what I get as failure in the logs:

```
Warning: Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: Can't write [/tmp/tmpnnIEUo/android/ForgeInspector/build/intermediates/transforms/proguard/vanilla/release/jars/3/1f/main.jar] (Can't read [/tmp/tmpnnIEUo/android/ForgeInspector/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/support-v4/23.4.0/jars/classes.jar(;;;;;;**/*.class)] (Duplicate zip entry [android/support/v4/d/a.class == classes.jar:android/support/v4/os/AsyncTaskCompat.class]))
:ForgeInspector:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForVanillaRelease FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':ForgeInspector:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForVanillaRelease'.
java.io.IOException: Can't write [/tmp/tmpnnIEUo/android/ForgeInspector/build/intermediates/transforms/proguard/vanilla/release/jars/3/1f/main.jar] (Can't read [/tmp/tmpnnIEUo/android/ForgeInspector/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/support-v4/23.4.0/jars/classes.jar(;;;;;;**/*.class)] (Duplicate zip entry [android/support/v4/d/a.class == classes.jar:android/support/v4/os/AsyncTaskCompat.class]))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of our own private native modules need to be updated in order to get rid of this specific build error. We need to migrate those modules to the new gradle build system for native modules within trigger.io